# Does PyDEV predefined support parameters type?

Tags: python, pydev, predef

I have a function like this:

```
def get_entity(entity_class, entity_id):
    "get an entity by given entity id
    @type entity_class: type
    @type entity_id: long
    @rtype: entity_class
    "

    return entity_class.get(entity_id)
```

I wrote a *pypredef* file:

```
def get_entity(entity_class, entity_id):
    "
    @type entity_class: type
    @type entity_id: long
    "
    return entity_class
```

and added it to Predefined completions. But it does not work.